# Using importxml() in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to use the importxml function in google spreadsheets and am having trouble finding out what is wrong with my XPath. The importxtml function syntax is ("url","xpath"). Here is what I have:

```
=importxml("http://www.barchart.com/commodityfutures/Corn_Futures/ZC?search=ZC*", "//table[@id="dt1"]//td[2]")
```

I have looked through some other examples and am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. The column that is titled "last" is what I am trying to return.

Comment: What's the problem? I tested your XPath in C# using HtmlAgilityPack. The same XPath scraping the same URL, and it returned correct values from column **Last**. Seems nothing wrong with the XPath.

Comment: Try to use single quotes for id value : `"//table[@id='dt1']//td[2]"` ?

Comment: Thanks guys! I just came back to say my mistake was the double quotes, and you already spotted it. I'm new to anything with code, so when I get anything to work out I get pretty excited.

Comment: @user3570871 Pretty much nothing was wrong with your question - I edited it slightly (more meaningful title to be better searchable, minor spelling, remove your introduction sentence). Question like that are a very good start - Welcome to SO!